# How can I fix this JSON TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python, json

I have read data from an API and the JSON file looks like this: 
`"{\"30days\":{\"dashboard\":{\"total_sessions\":{\"total\":12420,\"change\":\"2.4%\",\"trend\":\"u\"},\"new_users\":{\"total\":1255,\"change\":\"-6.6%\",\"trend\":\"d\"},\"total_users\":{\"total\":1466,\"change\":\"-6.3%\",\"trend\":\"d\",\"is_estimate\":false},...."`

```
 with open ("data_file.json", "r") as f:
    data1 = json.load(f)

results = data1['30days']['dashboard']['total_users']
```

I get an error --> TypeError: string indices must be integers.

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong??

Comment: I can parse the string you posted (replacing the final `,....` with `}}}`) and the query works for me.

Comment: Does your file really have the extra pair of double-quotes? Your file doesn't contain an object; it contains a string whose value is a JSON object.

Comment: That is, `data1 = json.loads(json.load(f))` may work.

Comment: @chepner Thanks that worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its given is an array of dictionaries, try to print the value of data1, so you can see the structure better.

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(data1)
```

And try this:

```
results = data1[0]['30days']['dashboard']['total_users']
```